# Collecting Lat-Long in a Google Docs Form by adding script?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, geolocation, google-sheets, google-forms

So I need am trying to figure out a way to collect Lat long data and have it saved automatically when I fill a Google form on my phone. Is it possible as retracing address to plot is not possible for my use case.

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-the-geolocation-of-a-place-in-Google-Forms

I am trying the solution mentioned by Sameer in this Quora post but completely unable to make this code work. It doesn't have to be a Google form solution but an Open source solution which doesn't restrict my data to its platform might also work.

Comment: why not just use google mymaps? https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/6138031?hl=en&ref_topic=3024969

Answer (score 0):

There's a Google docs plugin I forget what it's called but it will geocode addresses and other things for you with lat and long.

Comment: I think it's called geocoder